# Possible to find out the sizes of data types (int, float, double, ...) on a system, without writing a C program?

Tags: c

Is it possible to find out the sizes of data types (int, float, double, ...) on a Linux system, without writing a C program?

Would the results for C same as for C++, and other programming languages in the same Linux system?

Comment: I am curious -- if you don't intend to write a C program, what difference does it make if C data types are one size rather than another?

Comment: @DavidCary For calling ABI's from a language other than C!

Answer (score 23):

If you know the definition of the data type you want you can use `getconf` to find these values out on most Unix systems.

```
$ getconf CHAR_BIT
8
```

The list of variables is defined in the man page `man limits.h` as well as here, `man sysconf`, in addition to being on disk. You can use `locate limits.h` to find it, it's often here: `/usr/include/linux/limits.h`.

Comment: With the caveat that this applies only to the platform's official C compiler. There may be alternative compilers, or alternative configurations (typically through command line options) of the official compiler, that lead to different sizes.

Comment: @Gilles - have you ever seen a way to actually list these variables out? I've been looking and cannot for the life of me find a tool that can do this. Seems like there would be. Also I was under the impression that getting these values through `getconf` was the safest way, so long as you say, I'm hitting "the" official compiler on the box.

Comment: The reliable way — and the way people use when they care, which is by and large when they want to compile a C program — is to compile a small C program. See how autoconf operates. `getconf` isn't so safe, unless you're calling the C compiler as `c89` or `c99` with (almost) no option.

Answer (score 15):

Kind of.

With gcc at least, this works:

```
$ cpp -dD /dev/null | grep __SIZEOF_LONG__
```

Anyway, why don't you want to write a C program to do it?  You could send a tiny C program to your compiler from the shell something like this:

```
binary=$(mktemp)
cat <<\EOF | cc -o $binary -x c -
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("int=%lu bytes\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("long=%lu bytes\n", sizeof(long));
}
EOF
$binary
rm $binary
```

The `-x c` tells the compiler the language is `C`, and the `-` means read from standard input.

On my system, the above prints:

```
int=4 bytes
long=8 bytes
```

Tested in gcc and clang.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.  You could scan `/usr/include/<arch>/limits.h`

For example, on my NetBSD amd64, `/usr/include/amd64/limits.h` would show:

```
#define CHAR_BIT        8               /* number of bits in a char */

#define SCHAR_MAX       0x7f            /* max value for a signed char */
#define SCHAR_MIN       (-0x7f-1)       /* min value for a signed char */

#define UCHAR_MAX       0xff            /* max value for an unsigned char */
#define CHAR_MAX        0x7f            /* max value for a char */
#define CHAR_MIN        (-0x7f-1)       /* min value for a char */

#define USHRT_MAX       0xffff          /* max value for an unsigned short */
#define SHRT_MAX        0x7fff          /* max value for a short */
#define SHRT_MIN        (-0x7fff-1)     /* min value for a short */

#define UINT_MAX        0xffffffffU     /* max value for an unsigned int */
#define INT_MAX         0x7fffffff      /* max value for an int */
#define INT_MIN         (-0x7fffffff-1) /* min value for an int */

#define ULONG_MAX       0xffffffffffffffffUL    /* max value for an unsigned long */
#define LONG_MAX        0x7fffffffffffffffL     /* max value for a long */
#define LONG_MIN        (-0x7fffffffffffffffL-1)        /* min value for a long */
```

Comment: This often works, but sometimes different compilers or compiler settings will lead to different sizes.

Comment: When i look at the limits.h in ubuntu it points at variables like -SHRT_MAX-, whose value is being derived by the C pre-processor. Where can I find that?

Comment: On debian systems you can find the header in `/usr/include/limits.h` .

Answer (score 8):

If you have perl installed you can get this from perl -V:

```
intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
alignbytes=8, prototype=define
```

Comment: Does that list what was used when perl was compiled? How would it know which compiler you want?

Answer (score 7):

No... it *is* possible to run binaries with different ideas of the sizes of basic types, particularly on 64 bit architectures. Recent Linux kernels on x86_64 can run native 32 bit binaries, and there is the [x32 ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) with 32 bit types.

The data type sizes are partly what the compiler uses. But it is clearly advantageous to (1) use types that the machine supports efficiently and (2) use types consistently from the low-level libraries through user applications. Having to handle several variants is just a mess.

Answer (score 7):

Sizes of data types are a property of a compiler (or ABI), not of the system. You can have multiple compilers using different sizes for data types on the same system.

Comment: This answer hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to parse and output the lines containing the strings referencing the data types:

```
{ shopt -s globstar; for i in /usr/include/**/*.h; do grep -HE '\b(([UL])|(UL)|())LONG|\bFLOAT|\bDOUBLE|\bINT' $i; done; }
```

This catches of course the definitions in `/usr/include/limits.h` so you'll get that plus more, sometimes with values, but mostly referencing what is set in `limits.h` which you can conveniently look at with the `getconf -a` and `ulimit -a` commands.